# How to set highlight by line and column in vimscript

Tags: vim

I'm trying to highlight a range in vim via a vimscript. I know how to set the selection:

```
setpos('.', [0,<LINE0>,<COL0>])
normal! v
setpos('.', [0,<LINE1>,<COL1>])
```

BUT, the selection will only highlight those lines/columns as long as that buffer is in focus. Switching to a different window will make it go away.

I am aware of the `match` command. It would be ideal, especially since it would let me use a defined highlight to define how it would be colored/styled. However, `match` only matches on a regex, not line/column.

How do I do this? Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 5):

In vim regex you can match on lines with the `\%<num>l` and columns with `\%<num>c` (Read `:help \%l` and `:help \%c`)

Example to match the 3rd line and 3rd column you can use

```
:match Error /\%3l\%3c./
```

The dot is needed since the matches are 0 width.

Comment: To highlight a rectangle: `:match Error /\%>6l\%<11l\%>2c\%<41c/`.